# How to delete all duplicates files in a directory?? Java

Tags: java

How could I write a code to be able to delete exactly the duplicates
that I get previously with this code.?? please be specific when
answering as I am new to java.I have very basic knowledge of java.

```
private static MessageDigest messageDigest;
    static {
        try {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot initialize SHA-512 hash function", e);
        }
    }
public static void findDuplicatedFiles(Map<String, List<String>> lists, File directory) {
        for (File child : directory.listFiles()) {
            if (child.isDirectory()) {
                findDuplicatedFiles(lists, child);
            } else {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(child);
                    byte fileData[] = new byte[(int) child.length()];
                    fileInput.read(data);
                    fileInput.close();
                    String uniqueFileHash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest(fileData)).toString(16);
                    List<String> list = lists.get(uniqueFileHash);
                    if (list == null) {
                        list = new LinkedList<String>();
                        lists.put(uniqueFileHash, list);
                    }
                    list.add(child.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("cannot read file " + child.getAbsolutePath(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
Map<String, List<String>> lists = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        FindDuplicates.findDuplicateFiles(lists, dir);
        for (List<String> list : lists.values()) {
            if (list.size() > 1) {
                System.out.println("\n");
                for (String file : list) {
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not read the entire contents of the file into memory.  The whole point of an InputStream is that you can read small, manageable chunks of data, so you don’t have to use a great deal of memory.

Imagine if you were trying to check a file that’s one gigabyte in size.  By creating a byte array to hold the entire content, you have forced your program to use a gigabyte of RAM.  (If the file were two gigabytes or larger, you wouldn’t be able to allocate the byte array at all, since an array may not have more than 2³¹-1 elements.)

The easiest way to compute the hash of a file’s contents is to [copy the file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)) to a [DigestOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/security/DigestOutputStream.html), which is an OutputStream that makes use of an existing MessageDigest:

```
messageDigest.reset();
try (DigestOutputStream stream = new DigestOutputStream(
    OutputStream.nullOutputStream(), messageDigest)) {

    Files.copy(child.toPath(), stream);
}

String uniqueFileHash = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest());
```